# Traffic of Opera Mini vs Mobile with Turbo

Tags: data-monitoring, opera-mini, opera-browser

How much traffic does Opera Mini user compared to Opera Mobile with Turbo enabled? I suppose it's less but I haven't seen any numbers.

Comment: Opera Mini and Opera Turbo uses the same rendering proxy. Essentially, Opera Mobile with Turbo is Opera Mini. I'd expect the bandwidth to be the same.

Comment: Certainly not. Opera Mobile with Turbo receives the webpage as-is, just compressed and in one single package, without having to make separate requests for images and other resources. Opera Mini receives a version that has been pre-rendered by Opera's servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found some numbers on [Opera's website](http://www.opera.com/mobile/features/): They claim that Mini compresses webpages by "up to" 90%, Turbo compresses them by 80%.